# Explain how the UNION operator in SQL works

Tags: sql

I know union will remove the duplicates but whether all the columns should have same value or any one of the columns can have same value

```
CusID   Country   Value
-----------------------
  1     India     1000
  2     US        2000
  3     SA        4000


ID    Country  Value 
----------------------
 1    SA        500
 2    US       2000
 4    RS       1000
```

Code:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Whether it will remove the CusID=1 or not

Comment: Didn't you try it?

Comment: _"Whether it will remove the CusID=1 or not"_ well what happened when you executed it before posting?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90e58/1/0

Answer (score 1):

> *Whether it will remove the CusID=1 or not*

No it will not remove it.

The `UNION` operator checks for duplicates by looking at **all** columns in the SELECT list (just like `DISTINCT` does). For CusID = 1 the values in the columns `country` and `value` are different so that row doesn't qualify as a duplicate.

The row with `CusID = 2` will however show up in the result only once, as that **is** a duplicate (all columns have the same values).